# Setting Html On Ajax Success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html that looks like this with several items

```
<div class="item">
    <p class="price">$388.00</p>
         <p class="part_number">VM2327T23A00T</p>
         <p class="real_price"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
    <p class="price">$88.00</p>
         <p class="part_number">AA327T23A00T</p>
         <p class="real_price"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
      <p class="price">$38.00</p>
         <p class="part_number">AA327T23A00T</p>
         <p class="real_price"></p>
      </div>
```

etc..

I am trying to iterate through each item and set its "real_price" to a value here is my code:

```
  jQuery('.part_number').each(function () {
                    parts.push(SearchSpring.jQuery(this).text());

                    SearchSpring.jQuery.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "RealTimePricing.aspx/TestInteraction",
                data: "{param1:'brit', param2: 'nick'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function (msg) {                 
                   jQuery("#real_price").html(msg.d);

                }
            }
        );
      });

                }
```

I am getting the correct "msg" on success (I can see this in firebug) but it never sets the html, also it only iterates through the each 1 time..

I am not sure why this isnt setting the html

```
  jQuery("#real_price").html(msg.d);
```

And why is my code not looping through all the ".part_number" tags in the html?

Comment: use a `.` symbol instead of `#` for starters... `#` is reserved for querying by `id`. I would write it like so: `$(".real_price").html(msg.d); `

Comment: Excellent. I'll post that as the Answer if you don't mind giving me a pretty green-check `:)`

Comment: `$(".real_price").html(msg.d);` will update all elements that match .real_price... So it is not the solution unless you want to update all real_prices with exactly the same values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class="real_price"` implies `.real_price`, but you have to make sure you're updating the correct element as well (there are several elements with that class). I suggest using `.next` as the element to update is next to each `.part_number` element:

```
jQuery(".part_number").each(function() {
   var $elem = jQuery(this).next(".real_price");
```

and then:

```
$elem.html(msg.d);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `.` symbol instead of `#`, which is reserved for querying by `id`. Also, you should do this in a way that accesses individual prices instead otherwise it will update all elements as stated below.

Comment: Haha... I simplified my answer.  nice catch.

Comment: Your solution updates all classes @pimvdb is correct in this.

Comment: @pixelbobby, i confirmed his question; so my sentence did make sense. Additionally I typed that comment while pim was writing his, he posted a tad earlier though.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update #real_price, which does not exists in your html. You can use the following:

`jQuery(this).parent(".item").find(".real_price").html( msg.d );` which updates the other child .real_price of the .item

Comment: `.closest` won't work here because `.real_price` is not a parent of `.part_number`.

Comment: `.closest()` actually travaerser the dom upwards: http://api.jquery.com/closest/ `Description: Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.`